# How to make a circle-like slider

Tags: android, slider

Recently I just encounter a problem in Android.
I wanna make a slider whose thumb slides along the circle path.
Is there any way to achieve this ??
Thanks in advance!!![image]

Comment: Can you post any image related to it.

Comment: @Andro_Selva I'm sorry but I cannot upload the image for my poor reputation. What I wanna do is to make the thumb slides along the circle-bar,like the Hula-hoop.

Comment: have you found a way, yet?